# Преобразовать массив в совместимый с Autocomplete Jquery

Tags: массивы, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Хочу использовать функцию `Autocomplete` для поиска по названиям статей.
Получаю с внешнего источника массив вида:

```
{
         ‘раздел_1’: {
                   id статьи1: ‘Название статьи1’,
                   id статьи2: ‘Название статьи2’,
                   id статьи3: ‘Название статьи3’
                   ...............
          },
          ‘раздел_2’: {
                   id статьи1: ‘Название статьи1’,
                   id статьи2: ‘Название статьи2’,
                   id статьи3: ‘Название статьи3’
                   ...............
          }
          ...............
}
```

Сохраняю это в массив inArr.
Далее формирую новый массив newArr из inArr - выдергиваю названия статей, таким образом:

```
for(var i in inArr){
    for(var j in inArr[i]){
        newArr[newarr.length]= inArr[i][j];
    }
}
```

Запуская функцию Autocomplete, получаю работающий поиск с подстановкой, НО как мне вытаскивать ID статьи и название раздела?

```
$('.search').autocomplete({
    source: newArr, minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".section").attr("value",ui.item.section);//тут пусто - естессно, ведь в новом массиве нет названий разделов
        $(".article_name").attr("value",ui.item.value);
        $(".article_id").attr("value",ui.item.id);//тут пусто - естессно, ведь в новом массиве нет ID
    }
});
```

Спасибо всем ответившим, вроде разобрался, сформировал из первого массива второй, по нему ищу, или это уже как объект... вроде все гут. Блин, не ожидал, что тот автокомплит ищет не по началу слова, а ищет совпадения букв и в середине слова и на конце.. не очень приятный нюанс. и решения для работы с уже загруженным массивом нет. есть решения при запросе каждый раз с удаленной базы данных. явно не мой вариант. я как раз специально ОДИН раз загружаю массив и дальше с ним идет работа без обращения на сервак... жаль жаль. погуглил - альтернатив-то и нет... кто-нибудь находил решение?

Comment: заполняйте ваш массив объектом в котором будут нужные вам поля, а также поля label - что будет показываться пользователю, value - какое значение

Comment: т.е. массив newArr формировать по другому? добавлять в цикле нужное?

Comment: да, [пересмотрите еще раз, что можно передавать свойству source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: ясно. спасибо. понял одно - напрямую массив inArr нельзя будет передать, так или иначе формировать из него новый массив как выше отписал??

Comment: ничего не понял из потока мыслей в последнем абзаце. может их переформулировать как-от?